# Need to add a Column to signify Active or Termed Status

Tags: t-sql, view

I am creating a table that has a variety of Employee data in fields. I need to add a column that will display an "Active" or "Termed" status based weather there is a date in the Termination Date column.

For example, If the employee has a date in the StartDate column but not in the EndDate column then the EmpStatus Column will return an "Active" status. If there is a date in the EndDate column then it will return a "Termed" Status.

I am loading a master table from a view is the fastest and easiest way to do it.

The question is, where can I find a script that will perform the function I need.

Comment: You want a [`CASE` expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EndDate is not null then 'Termed' 
            WHEN StartDate is not null then 'Active' 
            else 'unknown' end as EmpStatus
FROM employee
```